# How can QoS prioritize traffic if the data is encrypted?

Tags: networking, home-networking, qos

Encrypted data can only be read by the one who is sending and receiving it right? How does QoS prioritize data if it's common now that the data that is being sent is encrypted?

Comment: The packet data is encrypted but not the port the packet is being sent out.  A more detailed answer is impossible without a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, QoS doesn't prioritize according to the (encrypted) data in the first place – it prioritizes according to metadata found in the packet's header.

No matter which layer the encryption happens at, the packet will always retains an outermost header indicating its source and destination – if the original header *did* get encrypted, a new one still has to be added on top, so that the network would know where to deliver the packet, and in the same way QoS will know how to queue it.

*(If you put an IP packet in a box, you can write the address on the outside of the box. If you then put all that in a bigger box – you can *still* write the address on the outside of the bigger box.)*

For example, TLS (as in HTTPS) encrypts just application-layer data (the actual HTTP requests), but parameters like "TCP dst port 443" or "IP dst address 1.1.1.1" have to remain unencrypted. The same IP header is where the DSCP classifier for QoS is set, as well.

VPN software encrypts whole IP packets, but then they're put in *another* IP packet with its own source/destination. QoS has no way of knowing what kind of packet was inside the tunnel, so it only classifies according to the outer header. (However, some tunnels deliberately copy the "inner" DSCP value to the outer one, to aid QoS at the cost of some privacy.)

Even things like MACsec, which work at the Ethernet layer (encrypting even the IP header), still leave the Ethernet header unencrypted – and the 802.1Q VLAN tag which indicates Ethernet QoS class also remains unencrypted.